# How to get List<MyBean> and Aggregations with single query?

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I can get Aggregations with

```
Aggregations aggregations = elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>() {
        @Override
        public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
        return response.getAggregations();
    }
});
```

And I can get List with

```
List<MyBean> list = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, MyBean.class);
```

But the problem is how can i get both List and Aggregations with single query?